# Create pivot view in MySQL

Tags: mysql, view

We have a table where we are saving data row-wise. For example

```
Id Property_Name Value
-----------------------------
1  Name            XYZ    
1  Age             22
1  Location        India
```

I want to transform these rows in columns and create a view so that all parts of the application can query it as required. 
Since, MySQL doesn't have built-in pivoting functionality, with help of Google found solution to do pivoting dynamically at http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html 
The code basically reads as

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(property_name = ''',
      property_name,
      ''', value, NULL)) AS ',
      property_name
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM properties;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id, ', @sql, ' FROM properties GROUP BY item_id');
```

This works fine if I write stored procedure. However, as said above, I am intending to create view so that it can be used/queried just like normal table.
However, as I have understood, in MySQL, we can't use variable, dynamic query or stored procedures :-(
Not sure, how to achieve this. I have tried searching on SO and Google but haven't found any suitable way forward to create view or viable alternate.
Please advise.

Comment: do you have a fixed number of properties?

Comment: @ThomasG : No, If it is fixed there is other way "MAX(IF(property_name = 'color', value, NULL)) AS color" as suggested in the link I have shared in the post.

Comment: Then I see no way to make a view out of this in MySQL. The application should handle it

Comment: @ThomasG: Hmm. Any suggestion for alternate? I don't want to depend on individual approach when they query against pivoted table.