# How to create View in MySQL using rows from second table?

Tags: php, mysql, view

I need to create **VIEW in MySQL**. where each rows from first table should show as column in the second table.

**Here is some example:**

*table Appraisal_skills*

```
    +------------+
    | id |title  | 
    +------------+
    |  1 | TestA | 
    |  2 | TestB | 
    |  3 | TestC |
    |  4 | TestD | 
    +------------+
```

*Required View*:

```
    +--------+------------+-------+
    | TestA| TestB | TestC | testD|
    +----------+------------+------
    |      |       |       |      |
    |      |       |       |      |
    +----------+------------+-----+
```

Does anybody have an idea how to create view in this way? Any help would be Appreciated.

Comment: From where will the records `abc, cdf, efg,` etc. come ?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876977/

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in sql? It's generally best to handle display issues in application code

Comment: @KeyurPanchal:just dummy values ..i removed it now

Comment: @Strawberry:yes i am going to do with using mysql..any other way?please help me

Comment: Just google dynamic pivot

Comment: @Shanukk can you please show us our code please ? or you are just thinking how to do so ?

Comment: @Strawberry i google it  but haven't found any suitable way forward to create view